Buttons vs links (as visual UI elements)
Introduction:
I keep reading over different articles the mantra that "Links go places, buttons do things", but this simply does not make sense on basic semantic level. Going to a place is doing something. You cannot differentiate between visiting locations and actions, because visiting a location, is a subset of action.
To illustrate this with UI elements: pagination buttons are about visiting a location. Why have buttons become the convention then?
Same about tabs. Visually, tabs are types of buttons, yet they open a new location, albeit on the same page. Same about show/ hide buttons.
I think this guiding rule of location/ action is inherently flawed. I would correct it by choosing a more precise terminology "navigational actions" and "non-navigational actions". Navigational action would be anything which serves you a portion of content - no matter if that would be a new page, or modal, or progressive disclosure on the same page. Non-navigational actions would be all else - e.g. printing, sending, closing, maximizing, minimizing, etc.

Question:
With (or without) the assumption above, have you stumbled upon any research or could you share personal observations (from usability tests), whether users have the expectation that UI elements serving different types of actions (e.g. navigational, non-navigational, whatever) should visually look different, on the first place?
(To make it even more clear, the same question could be restated as "have you seen research/ personal observations, that if you randomly change some of the buttons on a given interface to links, and some of the links to buttons, and for the sake of greater mess, if you visually change the way buttons look (e.g. mixing the visual conventions for chips/ buttons/ tabs/ etc), users would get confused at all?")


"Links go places, buttons do things"

In my opinion, this is an overly simple, stereotyped and somewhat old statement.

I can hardly imagine this button www.google.com
Or this link Accept


This definition of both elements is much more complete and better clarifies the function inherent to each one:

Use buttons when the user-action causes a change in either back-end or the front-end of the website. For example, submitting a form, opening a pop-up or a modal or a pannel on the same page.
Use links when the user-action doesn’t affect the website at all. In this, the users are just readers or spectators of the site. For example, to navigate to the next page or an external source after viewing the content of the page.

Source digitala11y.com

Why do we use buttons for pagination, then, as stated in my original question? A pagination button does not change either back-end or the front-end of the website.

The essence of my question is about proof/ observations about user expectations. What is the proof/ observation that users have different expectations towards changes in either back-end or the front-end of the website and user actions which do not affect the website at all?

I can hardly imagine the button and link examples, too. But that is not the point. Those examples refer to what designers would produce. The point is about user reactions. Can you imagine a user to get confused if stumbling upon them? And is there any actual research/ personal observations on user reactions in such cases?

Assuming that our job is to make products which closely match the users' mental models, I don't think that a technical distinction such as back-end/front-end or affecting the website is an effective rule of thumb in this case. I think we can't expect users to be thinking in these terms.

I think that the mantra you quoted is actually a very good starting point.
Regarding the "semantic" problem - this is an oversimplification, you can't look at language this way. I think that it's pretty clear that the true meaning is "go places vs. do things other than going places". We have tons of expressions that don't make sense semantically, yet everyone understands them (e.g. "tons of expressions").
To continue with your example: pagination buttons aren't about visiting a location, they're about loading new content on the same screen, the user stays on the same place on the website but sees new stuff. Just like tabs - as you correctly pointed out.
Your "navigation actions as anything that serves a new portion of content" suggestion is a good example here. I think there's a lot of difference between me going to another room to get something, and having someone else fetch it for me while I stay in the same place. The first is navigation, the second is an action, but both serve me new content, and I believe this distinction is important if we want the user to understand how our product works.
Now to the actual question
As I said, I think that the original mantra is a good starting point - for someone who is completely new to this and have no idea what they're doing, it's a nice rule of thumb. The rest of us understand that it is quite outdated and things have changed a bit in the past 20 years. It's all about styling, buttons may look like links and links may look like buttons. There are exactly three buttons on the current page on this website: Learn more, Ask question, and Post your answer. But there are many more links that perform actions - Add a comment, Edit, Discard, Share, Follow, Flag etc. Also, there are many dozens of links leading to other places - all the usernames, promoted/related questions  and nav menu. So on this website buttons signify primary actions, and links mark secondary actions, whether navigational or not.
And to the answer
Users have come to understand that the styling choices are different on the different websites and apps, and they (unconsciously) try to figure them out when they land on a new product. What will confuse them is a website not being consistent with itself, and not having a clear internal convention on what's a link and what's a button on that site. If I were to consistently switch between links and buttons overnight in an existing product, returning users would be confused for a while, and first-time users wouldn't feel a thing. If I did that in an inconsistent and an unpredictable way, everybody would be confused all the time.

"pagination buttons aren't about visiting a location, they're about loading new content on the same screen" - that is correct from technical point of view, but how does it make sense from UI point of view, from the user's perspective? If I click on a show hide-button, it does open new content for me and that is new location for me. Think about a left sidebar - technically it could be implemented as either tabs or buttons opening new pages. Visually both can be made to look exactly the same. The only difference would be in loading times and changes in the URL.

"Users have come to understand that the styling choices are different..." - can you refer to research or personal observations on this? My question is about evidence or at least empirical clues on user expectations regarding links/ buttons.

Completing my first comment about pagination: by your definitions, users should perceive the left sidebar differently, whether it would be technically implemented as tabs or buttons loading new pages. But visually it would look exactly the same. What would make me have different expectations then, as a user?

The technical side is irrelevant here, since as you say visually it can look the same. We're talking purely about design. It's your job to tell the user "to get the info you requested I'm moving you to a different part of the website, i.e. navigation is happening, and THIS  is the means to navigate on my site". Or "I'm loading the info for you on the same page, the navigational context remains the same and THIS control performed this (non-navigational) action".

"It's your job to tell the user..." - but who proved that the user has expectations to be informed if their navigational journey happens on a different page or on the same page, so as to have such a job on the first place?

The whole intention of differentiating between button and link lies on the presumption that moving from one page to another is considered navigation, while things happening on the same page, such as opening an accordion or tabs, is not navigation. This is ridiculous. This is why I gave the example with left sidebar above. If the sidebar is structured, in terms of code, as buttons opening new pages, then we should call it navigation (by your logic), but if it is structured as tabs, we should no longer consider it navigation? This makes no sense, as visually, in terms of UI, it is the same.

You misunderstand my logic. I explicitly said that the code is irrelevant, it's purely about design. It is the designer's job to help the user use the product. One of the means we have at our disposal is navigation. It reflects the information architecture of the product and helps us to break apart the product's complexity. When they interact with the UI, stuff happens. You decide what happens exactly. It's now your job to explain to the user what happened. It's not about navigation  specifically. It's about using different metaphors for different types of interaction so as not to confuse them

And I am asking, how exactly does the differentiation between navigating between pages and navigating within the same page, reflect any corresponding differentiation in the user's mental model about navigating a web site (so as to resort to using visually different UI elements (buttons and links) to denote the two different navigation modes)? Put it simpler, what is the evidence that there's any meaningful difference to a user whether they would be navigating between pages or within the same page?

One of the most basic measures of usability is predictability. Navigation implies a change of context. Context is important, and we pay a high cognitive price for context switching. Staying within the same page is safer in that sense. The difference between the two needs to be predictable. Furthermore, the more different actions I have on a website, the more important it becomes to break them down into groups. The distinction between navigation and actions is an easy and basic way of doing that. It's not about "navigation vs action" as such, it's about the goals of this differentiation.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
